# How to make the first column of my <table> not movable when I scroll table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, custom-scrolling

My table is put inside div style = "overflow:auto" but I want the first column to stay on its place while all other columns scrollling.

Answer (score 1):

add `style="position:fixed;top:100px;left:50px"` to the row you would like to fix (you can adapt the px values).